# Does `fetch` withCredential option not work on the server side?

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api

I am using Next.js app router and fetching data using `fetch` API on the server side.

I applied `withcredential: include` to the `fetch` option, but looking at the log of the request target server, the cookie is null.

When I log `headers().get('Cookie')` within the API fetch function, the cookies stored in the existing browser are successfully received, but when fetching, the cookies do not appear to be included in the request.

Therefore, my inference is that fetch's `withCredential` only works on the client side.

I'd like to hear two answers:

1. Does fetch's `withCredential` only work on the client side?
2. I would like to know the detailed operation of fetch's `withCredential`.

Comment: Cookies are a browser feature. The server sends the cookie to the browser, the browser sends it back in requrests. Servers don't have a cookie store, so they don't send cookies in requests.